# Pandas data slicing by column names

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning Pandas and trying to understand slicing. Everything makes sense expect when I try to slice using column names. My data frame looks like this:

```
              area       pop
California  423967  38332521
Florida     170312  19552860
Illinois    149995  12882135
New York    141297  19651127
Texas       695662  26448193
```

and when I do `data['area':'pop']` I expected both columns to show since I am using explicit index and both the start and end of the slice should be inclusive, but the result is an empty dataframe.

I also get an empty dataframe for `data['area':]`. Why is this different from slicing with explicit indexes elsewhere?

Comment: I posted an answer showing how the indexing works in your case. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges)

> With DataFrame, slicing inside of [] **slices the rows**. This is provided largely as a convenience since it is such a common operation.

You get an empty DataFrame because your index contains strings and it can't find values 'area' and 'pop' there. Here what you get in case of numeric index

```
>> data.reset_index()['area':'pop']
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [area] of <class 'str'>
```

What you want instead is

```
>> data.loc[:, 'area':'pop']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the 2 columns use:

```
import pandas as pd

#data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = True)

all = data[['area','pop']]
```

*So you can pass a list of columns to [] to select columns in that order.*

Similarily, to get only the area column use:

```
area = df[['area']]
```

Now, if you want to get **the values of the columns** use:

```
all = data[['area','pop']].values
area = df[['area']].values
```

The `all` and `area` are going to be numpy arrays.